# Is this sentecne correct? 'It was only after I started studying for a BA degree in Sociology that I became interested in...'

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, sequence-of-tenses, tense-agreement

> It was only after I started studying for a BA degree in Sociology
> that I became interested in how people from dysfunctional families
> become parents.

Is 'studying for a BA degree in smth' a correct phrase?
Can I use the present simple for the last part of the sentence even though my actual sentence is about the past?

Comment: Yes and yes. The last part of the sentence is about people's behaviour in general, not what was happening while you were studying.